# How to validate a mongorestore

Tags: mongodb-3.2

I have a script that creates a zip dump file using `mongodump` for all of my sibling databases in Mongo. I then transfer these to a different mongoDB instance(having the same sibling dbs) and use `mongorestore` to fill up the collections and their respective documents.
The db version is `v3.2.19`

Does anybody know of a way or direct me to some resource that helps validating the two mongo processes (preferably programmatically)? I would like to say for certain that the number of documents/collections dumped were the number of documents/collections inserted using restore.

Thanks again!

Comment: Can you share the `mongodump` and `mongorestore` command and parameters that you are using? It will have an impact on what comparisons can be done.