# mongorestore - documents fail validation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-4.0, mongodb-4.2

The similar question already have been asked: [How to validate a mongorestore](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/209564/how-to-validate-a-mongorestore)

But how to actually validate the documents in mongodumb and mongorestore?
And also - can I see the documents that fail validation and why do they fail it?

The commands I am using:

```
mongodump -d my_database -o ~/dump --gzip
mongorestore --drop --gzip dump
```

The mongo is of  4.x.x version (4.0.10 and 4.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

If only needing to **validate**, the best combination would be to add `--dryRun --objcheck --verbose` or `--dryRun --objcheck -vvvvv` to your mongorestore command.

When running the command for **real**, drop the `--dryRun`.